# iframe with local .html content

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a project that is supposed to display html content in iframe. The content is located in server directories away from project root. Kind of like a static file with some additional javascript and CSS. I struggle to find a way to provide the file location to iframe while using relative path.

Say file **example.html** is located on server **C:/Content/Alpha/example.html** a long with JS and CSS.

Physical path does not work because browsers blocks it therefore i need to use relative path similar to ASP views (localhost:45644/Home/Index) but instead of pointin to controller  would like to point to the file mentioned above

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example; you are missing important information about your issue for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way finally

This is possible by using `HttpResponseBase.Controller.Response` class. I read the file from disk using File stream, and then send the data to the client with Response.OutputStream.Write();

See code below

```
private void FLushFileToClient(string filePath) {

    Response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = false;

    using (Stream _stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        long _long_bytesToRead = _stream.Length;
        while (_long_bytesToRead > 0)
        {

            if (Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                byte[] _buffer = new Byte[1000];
                int _readLength = _stream.Read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
                Response.OutputStream.Write(_buffer, 0, _readLength);

                _long_bytesToRead -= _readLength;
            }
            else
            {
                _long_bytesToRead = -1;
            }
        }
        
    }
    Response.Flush()
}
```